# Can I print at a decimal scale using Preview?

Tags: mac, printing

I'm new to Mac OS and I'm trying to print at a scale of 88.7% which always ends up rounded to 89%. Is there a default to set/unset for this behavior to stop occurring?

Comment: Hmmmm... does it in PDF Expert as well. It may be a system-wide setting.

Comment: RE: "Is there a default to set/unset for this behavior to stop occurring?" --  I seriously doubt that there is as **Preview** is a very low end _application_ in what it can do compared to other _applications_. For example, when printing graphic images or .pdf documents, and  using the free  [**GIMP for macOS**](https://www.gimp.org/downloads/) _application_, when I set it at `88.7%` it stays at `88.7%`.  If you have a _file_ type that needs printing that **GIMP** can't handle, obviously you'd need to find a different _application_, maybe, for .pdf _files_, **Adobe Acrobat Reader DC**.

Comment: Are you trying to fill a particular sheet size? You can tell the Print dialog to fill the page to the sheet, which may be more accurate.